# How to do a persistent notification in React-Native? (Not swipeable)

Tags: react-native

I'm doing a "Uber like"app, and i want to do a persistent notification, as shown below, to let the driver know his status (connected, searching for rides, disconnected, etc). I've implemented push notifications trough Firebase, but they quite solve my problem, but it's not how i think is the best way. Does anyone know how to do that? [WhatsApp implementation on what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTZXL.png)

Comment: I can suggest 1 paid react native library for perform this if it is ok to use paid library for you.